# How to setvalue on onload event in Dynamics crm

Tags: fetch, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I'm getting a record using fetch to client side, and I need to fill the data from the fetch into a field in a new record I create (fill field on client side), but when I use set value I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'setValue' of null

I don't understand why, the field is `Null` because the new record is empty, why can't I fill it?

```
function OnLoad() {
  formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
  if(formType == formTypes.Create){
    copyCatNewRecord();
  }
}

function copyCatNewRecord(){
  var xml;
  xml ="<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' count='1'>"
  xml += "<entity name='needs'>"
  xml += "<attribute name='needsid' />"
  xml += "<attribute name='needsname' />"   
  xml += "<order attribute='modifiedon' descending='true' />"
  xml +=  "</entity></fetch>"

  var ret = frameworkGlobal.ExecuteFetchRequest(xml);
  var currValue = ret[0].needsid.Value;

  // This line returns an error  
  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("needs").setValue(currValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot read property 'setValue' of null

This error message is usually received when `Xrm.Page.getAttribute()` has been called on a field that doesn't exist. So, are you sure that `"needs"` is the schema name of an actual field on your form? The field should probably have a prefix such as `new_` i.e. `"new_needs"`

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are receiving indicates that the field you are trying to write data was not found. Make sure the field is present on the form and that you are using the logical name when trying to access it (see Dave Clark's answer).

In case you are trying to set the value from a Html webresource present on your form use `window.parent` to access the field >  `window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("prefix_fieldname").setValue(currValue);`